# DateTime objects in MeteorJS and Redux

Tags: meteor, react-native, react-redux

What is best practice to deal with DateTime objects in MeteorJS with Redux?

Lately implemented the usage of Redux in my React Native + Meteor app for offline functionality following the blog post of [Spencer Carli](https://hackernoon.com/offline-first-react-native-meteor-apps-2bee8e976ec7#.g69svm3zl). But I have some problems with the way both systems store DateTime objects. I must admit that I have no detailed understanding of how date objects are handled in JavaScript.

**Meteor**

My Meteor collection model contains a datetype object (I use `simpl-schema`):

```
const Objects= new Mongo.Collection('objects');
Objects.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  startedAt: Date,
});
```

**Date presentation**

In the react-native app I have to parse the date type to a string:

```
<Text>Started at: {object.startedAt.toUTCString()}</Text>
```

However, in disconnected mode the date is of type string `“2017-02-11T09:00:00.000Z”` so this parse fails

**Insert items with a Date object**

The insert of items in react-native:

```
Meteor.collection('objects').insert({
    startedAt: new Date(),
  }
);
```

This is accepted in disconnected mode, but when connection with the server is restored, insertion of items in the MongoDB is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not a great answer my primary suggestion, whenever using dates in Javascript, is to use the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). It will save you a *ton* of time.

Otherwise, and I'm not sure if this is the "right" approach, I would do

`<Text>Started at: {new Date(object.startedAt).toUTCString()}</Text>`

that way the startedAt value will always be converted to a Date object, regardless of it it's already one or if it's a string.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works for the presentation indeed. But I still cannot insert objects with Date type documents

Comment: That's odd. Does it work when online (not from disconnected to reconnected, just online in general)? If not then it may be a simple schema issue